# A single word for "too expensive"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have to decide between software A and B and both of them are $100, but software B is worth less than its asking price. What can I say instead of:

> Software B is **expensive**

Comment: *Overpriced*, perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by mick, software B is **overpriced**

> - (adj) - too costly for the value,    [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overpriced)  -  e.g. "overpriced items at resort shops"
> - (verb)  to give a price that is too high to (something) [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overprice) e.g. "everything in that store is grossly overpriced"

Comment: Properly converted to a Community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

> Software B is a **ripoff**.
>
> **[Ripoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripoff)**: A ripoff (or rip-off) is a bad financial transaction. Usually it refers to an incident in which a person is overcharged for
>   something, or receives goods or services not of the standard expected
>   for the price.

Comment: Nope. A ripoff is much more general than overpricing - it has many more meanings. Nor is it limited to a "financial transaction" - it can include theft or copying. @Mick's comment is the best answer (so far): software B is *overpriced*.

Answer (score 1):

> software B is too expensive for what it's worth.

You could say it's ***not cost-effective***:

> **cost-effective** - effective or productive in relation to its cost : *the most cost-effective way to invest in the stock market.*

New Oxford American Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **overpriced**, why not consider **Pricey** ?

pric- ey
or pricy
1.
[ prahy -see]
adjective , pricier, priciest.
expensive or unduly expensive:
a pricey wine.

Answer (score -1):

Pyrrhic maybe? 
-achieved at excessive cost ; also :  costly to the point of negating or outweighing expected benefits  (from websters)
It would be awkward to use it that way but the definition kind of fits?